# Eigenvalues of Symmetric Matrix Plus Diagonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $M$ be a real symmetric matrix and let $D$ be a real diagonal matrix.

> Can we say something about the eigenvalues of $M+D$ in terms of the
>   eigenvalues of $M$?

For example, if $D$ is a constant multiple of $I$ ($D = cI$), then the eigenvalues of $M+D$ is just $c$ plus the eigenvalues of $M$. Can we get bounds on the locations of the eigenvalues of $M+D$ ?

Comment: You might be able to do something pretty crude with the spectral radius.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yea so you can get some weak bounds on by using the   Gershgorin circle theorem but hopefully there is something better for this very special case

Comment: What if $M$ is also a positive circulant matrix?

Answer (score 8):

Your question is equivalent to this one

let $A,B$ be symmetric real matrices, the spectra of which, are known. What can be said about $spectrum(A+B)$ ?

This question was the subject of Horn's conjecture that lists all the possible values of $spectrum(A+B)$.

This very difficult conjecture was proved in 1999 by Klyachko, Knutson and the inevitable Tao.

cf. this paper by Bhatia and the references inside.

http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~ressayre/PDFs/bhatia.pdf

Answer (score 6):

I don't think anything strong can be said in general; there is no nice relationship between the eigenvalues of $M$ and $M+D$ even in the case when $M$ is $2\times 2$ or diagonal.

Obviously $M+D$ is a spectral shift (by 1) of the *generalized* eigenvalues of $M$ with respect to $D$, and you can prove some bounds on the minimum and maximum eigenvalues of $M+D$ in terms of those of $M$ and $D$, etc.